# How to print a horizontal row of numbers with user input in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a program that asks the user to enter a number 
n, where -6 < n < 93.

output: Enter the start number: 12

12 13 14 15 16 17 18

The numbers need printed using a field width of 2 and are right-justified. Fields need separated by a single space. There should be no spaces after the final field.

This is my code so far:

```
a = eval(input('Enter the start number : ',end='\n'))

for n in range(a,a+7):
    print("{0:>2}").format(n)
    print()
```

But it says:

```
File "C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/row.py", line 5, in <module>
    a = eval(input('Enter the start number : ',end='\n'))
builtins.TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `input` function returns a `string`. You should cast it as integer.

Also you have some syntax error, to name a few:

1. You put `.format` after print, but it should be inside the `print` and after the string.
2. The `input` function doesn't take an `end` argument. And python gives you this error for that: `TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments`
3. The formatting pattern is not right.

This code does what you want:

```py
    a = int(input('Enter the start number between -6 and 93: '))
    assert (n >= -6) and (n <= 93), f"number must be in [-6, 93]," \ 
            f"but got {n} instead"
    for n in range(a, a+7):
        print(f"{n:02d}", end=' ')
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the start number : 12
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the space between the user input and the output

Comment: What do you mean? you want the output to be printed on the same line as input?

Comment: alternative way to print is to use the variadic argument `print(*[f"{n:02d}" for n in range(a, a+7)], end=" ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass \n to input beacouse is a special character.

If you want a white line add another print() after the input.

Comment: thank you but is there also anything wrong with the calculation

Answer (score 1):

`input()` doesn't take the end argument, only `print()` does.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```py
# input(): takes the input from the user, that will be in the form of string
# rstrip(): will remove the white spaces present in the input
# split(): will convert the string into a list
# map(function, iterable) : typecast the list

ar = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
print(ar)
```

**output**:

```
1 2 3 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```